# Amazon Lex - Lambda response return HTML to bot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I'm returning a message from Lambda to the Lex Bot like this:

```
return Close(
    sessionAttributes,
    "Fulfilled",
    new LexResponse.LexMessage {
        contentType = "PlainText",
        content = "Thanks"
    }
);
```

Is it possible to return HTML as the content, even an iframe to external content?

`contentType` doesn't seem to have an option for HTML, is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Whatever you are putting in the `content` will be returned to the client, parsing of the message is the job of client you are using.

So if you are putting `content = "<h1>Thanks</h1>"` to a website you are using as chat client, then it will be displayed as heading. Browser will be able to format it accordingly.

Note: its **contentType** and **content**, i.e first letter is in small-case.

Hope it helps.